# What is the precise definition of the environment a qubit lives in?

Tags: quantum-state, noise

The book *An Introduction to Quantum Computing* (section 10.4.1 Error Models for Quantum Computing) by Phillip Kaye, Raymond Laflamme and Michele Mosca states the following:

> *Errors occur on a qubit when its evolution differs from the desired one. This difference can occur due to imprecise control over the
>   qubits or by interaction of the qubits with an environment. By
>   ‘environment’, we mean everything external to the qubit under
>   consideration. A ‘quantum channel’ is a formal description of how
>   qubits in a given setting are affected by their environment.*

I would like to know what *is* the environment and what are the physical characteristics that describe it.

Furthermore, does the qubit alone generate noise within itself (assuming that no noise is generated from its environment)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of the system/environment description is that the "system" is the bit that you can characterise and control. The environment is the bit that you cannot characterise or control. It could be anything. Ultimately, it's the whole of the rest of the Universe. For your particular physical realisation, you might have some approximation of what the environment might be doing, but it is very much case dependent.

> Furthermore, does the qubit alone generate noise within itself (assuming that no noise is generated from its environment)?

That might come down to a matter of definition. *All* non-unitary evolution can be described by reference to a larger system, i.e. an environment, on which the evolution is unitary. If no noise is generated from the environment, i.e. if the qubit and environment are decoupled, then the evolution of the qubit should be unitary, and there is no noise.

On the other hand, what about things like the spontaneous emission of an atom? That *sounds* like a qubit alone generating its own noise. I'm not an expert on this (I'm relying on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_emission)!) but, basically, if you want to describe this using regular quantum, you have to introduce an environment (e.g. Jaynes-Cummings model). A proper description uses quantum electrodynamics, at which point you possibly could describe it as a qubit generating its own noise.

Answer (score 0):

The concept is as general as thermodynamics.

Universe = System + Environment + System-Environment-coupling

If there is no coupling there will be no information exchange between the system and the environment. In this case the system is isolated. You can imagine a system like cold water isolated from a hot desertic environment via a thermos bottle. If a system is coupled to the environment you can imagine this like having cold water inside a cup in a desert. In a cup, the water will exchange heat with the hot desertic environment. It will eventually assume the temperature of the hot environment. This is an example for a system more strongly coupled to its environment.

- Qubits are considered the quantum system.
- The cavity environment + quantum control devices (and everything further outside, such as the room in which the experiment is held, are considered the environment.
- Qubits are not fully isolated from their environment. There will be information exchange which can be interpreted thermodynamically as energy and heat exchange. Microscopically, this is can described by the exchange of photons between the system (emission/absorption) and environment entanglement via quantum control operations.

As a fun fact, system and environment can be swapped around though typically one would fixate the system as the interesting system of study and the environment logically as everything not included in the system. If you are not interested in the many degrees of freedom of your environment, you can collectively average out all of them and characterize the environment  by a few effective quantities which can even be those such as temperature, pressure, friction quantities, etc.

Mathematically preciser using quantum mechanics:

H = H(system)+ H(bath) + H(system-bath-coupling)

Check for yourself this great qubit noise modelling review motivated by open quantum systems theory:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.00967